# Different display on GitHub pages

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I’m new to programming and I deployed my first project to github pages but I am encountering 2 problems:

1. The desktop version is perfect! But when I open the site on my mobile or Ipad, the cards on the home page are not separated. In my live server and on responsive tools it appears separated. But in any case, I tried adding margin, etc. and it didn’t work.
2. I’ve heard that when you upload a file to a server you should create a Css folder, an image folder, JS, etc. I understand that. But I didn’t understand when people say you should put your html pages (except index) on a “static” directory and leave the index on the root directory. Why is that?

Here is my github site: https://bmg1612.github.io/blog-udacity/

Here is the HTML of the index page:

```css
/* Home page */
      .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: min-content;
        justify-content: space-between;
        grid-template-areas:
          "hd"
          "feat"
          "main"
          "ft";
      }
    
      .menu {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
      }
    
      .featured-post {
        grid-area: feat;
        padding: 0 20px;
        border-bottom: 2px dotted #ffffff;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        background-image: url("../img/feat-post-img.png");
        background-size: contain;
      }
    
      .feat-post-link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
      }
    
      .hd-feat-post {
        color: #dcbff3;
        padding-top: 0px;
      }
    
      .txt-feat-post {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        padding-top: 0px;
      }
    
      .main-home {
        grid-area: main;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 20px;
        margin: 30px 30px;
      }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Personal Blog Website</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
      <a href="#main-content" class="skip-link">Skip to main content</a>
      <!-- Grid -->
      <div class="grid-container">
          <!--Flexbox menu-->
          <header class="nav-top">
              <ul class="menu">
                  <li class="logo">Blog Template</li>
                  <li class="item home-link">
                      <a class="link-nav focus" href="index.html">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="item">
                      <a class="link-nav focus" href="static/about.html">About</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </header>
          <div role="banner" class="featured-post">
              <a href="static/blog-post.html" class="feat-post-link" aria-label="Featured blog post" id="main-content">
                  <h1 class="hd-feat-post">Featured post</h1>
                  <h2 class="txt-feat-post">Brief description of the featured post</h2>
                  <figcaption>Background image - Stars in the sky</figcaption>
              </a>
          </div>
          <!--Flexbox content-->
          <main class="main-home">
              <article class="article-card">
                  <img src="img/blog-post.jpg" alt="Blog post" class="blog-img" />
                  <a href="static/blog-post.html" class="article-link">
                      <h2 class="post-title">Blog post</h2>
                      <p class="blog-txt">Brief description of the post</p>
                  </a>
              </article>
              <article class="article-card">
                  <img src="img/blog-post.jpg" alt="Blog post" class="blog-img" />
                  <a href="static/blog-post.html" class="article-link">
                      <h2 class="post-title">Blog post</h2>
                      <p class="blog-txt">Brief description of the post</p>
                  </a>
              </article>
              <article class="article-card">
                  <img src="img/blog-post.jpg" alt="Blog post" class="blog-img" />
                  <a href="static/blog-post.html" class="article-link">
                      <h2 class="post-title">Blog post</h2>
                      <p class="blog-txt">Brief description of the post</p>
                  </a>
              </article>
              <article class="article-card">
                  <img src="img/blog-post.jpg" alt="Blog post" class="blog-img" />
                  <a href="static/blog-post.html" class="article-link">
                      <h2 class="post-title">Blog post</h2>
                      <p class="blog-txt">Brief description of the post</p>
                  </a>
              </article>
              <article class="article-card">
                  <img src="img/blog-post.jpg" alt="Blog post" class="blog-img" />
                  <a href="static/blog-post.html" class="article-link">
                      <h2 class="post-title">Blog post</h2>
                      <p class="blog-txt">Brief description of the post</p>
                  </a>
              </article>
              <article class="article-card">
                  <img src="img/blog-post.jpg" alt="Blog post" class="blog-img" />
                  <a href="static/blog-post.html" class="article-link">
                      <h2 class="post-title">Blog post</h2>
                      <p class="blog-txt">Brief description of the post</p>
                  </a>
              </article>
          </main>
          <footer class="footer">
              <h1>Contact</h1>
              <form class="newsletter" method="POST">
                  <h2 aria-owns="label-email text" class="subscribe-ft">
                      Subscribe to our newsletter
                  </h2>
                  <label class="label-email" for="text">Enter your email:</label>
                  <input type="email" id="text" name="E-mail" class="focus" />
                  <input type="submit" id="send" aria-label="Submit" value="Submit" class="focus" />
              </form>
          </footer>
      </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Here is the CSS for the mobile layout:

The CSS are on 3 files, here is the link : https://github.com/Bmg1612/blog-udacity/

[image: And here it is how it looks when I open the page on my mobile]

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML in the question.

Comment: I don't know but while inspecting through various phones, everything seems to be working fine

Comment: Yeah I checked the zoom of my phone it is on standard.. maybe is something that the iphone/browser does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reproduce your issue on mac Safari, under responsive design mode (so displaying the page as if I am on an iPhone). Looks like the `gap: 20px` property does not work on Safari?

Anyway, a possible workaround to `gap: 10` would be to use margins on the articles themselves, e.g.:

```
.article-card {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```